# ASP.NET Mock Failed SignInResult is returning Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

In my test project i am using **xUnit** with **Moq**.

now i want to unit test these piece of code in the controller:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,
                                                      model.Password, 
                                                      model.RememberMe, 
                                                      lockoutOnFailure: false);

if (result.Succeeded) {}
```

in order to do that, i'm need to mock the `PasswordSignInAsync` function so it returns a success/failed `SignInResult`

the setup in the unit test class:

```
//Arrange
var _loginViewModel = _fixture.Build<LoginViewModel>()
    .OmitAutoProperties().With(l => l.Email).Create();
var applicationUser = _fixture.Create<ApplicationUser>();
_signInManager.Setup(s => s
                .PasswordSignInAsync(applicationUser,
                        _loginViewModel.Password,
                        _loginViewModel.RememberMe,
                        false))
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success));
//Act
IActionResult result = await _sutAccountController.Login(_loginViewModel, null);
ViewResult? viewResult = result as ViewResult;
```

but when debbuging the test method, the funtion `PasswordSignInAsync` always returns `null`

------ *Edit*: *Removing unnecessary code*

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: return using `ReturnsAsync` for async mock setup method. Use `.ReturnsAsync(SignInResult.Success)`

Comment: Did you hit the signature correct and are the used types comparable? For example is applicationUser the same instance that is used by the code under test that calls PasswordSignInAsync?

Comment: Also the `ReturnsAsync(SignInResult.Success)` returned null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking the wrong overload of [`PasswordSignInAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0), you have mocked the one that takes a user object instead of the one that takes the email address which is what is actually being called in your first snippet.

Try this instead:

```
_signInManager.Setup(s => s
    .PasswordSignInAsync(
        It.IsAny<string>(), // Feel free to replace this with an actual email
        _loginViewModel.Password,
        _loginViewModel.RememberMe,
        false))
    .ReturnsAsync(SignInResult.Success);
```

Comment: thanks a lot David, O M G how i didn't see that